# XDocument.parse parsing string as one element

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

While i am using XDocument.parse it parses entire string as one element .The parsed document has no structure.I am using regex to find XML string I need to work on.Here is my code

```
int total=1;
                List<XDocument> documents = new List<XDocument>();

                Match collection = Regex.Match(innerXMl, @"<claimDetails" + total + @">[\s\S]+          
                <\/claimDetails" + total + ">");

                Regex regex = new Regex(@"<[\/]{0,1}?claimDetails"+total+">");

                System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

                if (collection.Success)
                {

                    string value = collection.Value;
```

Value of `value` variable is

```
<claimDetails1>
  <regNo1>DL12SG7754</regNo1>
  <chasisNo1>ME4JF505EG7144924</chasisNo1>
  <engineNo1>JF50E73144192</engineNo1>
  <insurerName1>Shriram General Insurance Co. Ltd.</insurerName1>
  <typeOfClaim1>OD</typeOfClaim1>
  <dateOfLoss1>2020-02-06</dateOfLoss1>
  <claimIntimationDate1>2020-02-12</claimIntimationDate1>
  <ODClaimsPaid1>8954</ODClaimsPaid1>
  <whetherTotalLossClaim1>No</whetherTotalLossClaim1>
  <whetherTheftClaim1>No</whetherTheftClaim1>
  <totalTPClaimsPaid1>0.0</totalTPClaimsPaid1>
  <tpOpenClaimProvison1>0</tpOpenClaimProvison1>
  <tpCloseClaimProvison1>0</tpCloseClaimProvison1>
  <expensesPaid1>0</expensesPaid1>
  <claimstatus1>Claim Fully settled</claimstatus1>
  <searchBasedOn1>REG_NUM</searchBasedOn1>
</claimDetails1>
```

I want to parse this into Xdocument.

```
                    documents.Add(XDocument.Parse(value));
                }
```

Above line parses value variable into Xdocument object with no error but entire document has only single element that is `claimDetails1` and `innerXml as entire thing in between`.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

XDocument.Parse creates an XDocument from the string you pass. And then you use the XDocument to deserialize the XML to get the required values.

Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=netcore-3.1

Your question is not entirely clear and also not sure what you mean by 'no structure' (i.e. is it a bad xml that doesnt parse or just randomly structured data), so I'll update my answer if its not what you're looking for.

```
List<XElement> documents = new List<XElement>();
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(EntireXMLstring);
if (xdoc.Descendants("claimDetails1").Any())
{
    IEnumerable<XElement> requiredNode = xDoc.Descendants("claimDetails");
    documents.AddRange(requiredNode);
}
```